# Confusion with Java generics and subclassing

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, subclassing

I have the following:

- An abstract class `BaseScore`
- `LevelScore` which is a subclass of `BaseScore`

I then have:

- An abstract class `BaseScoreRecord`

  ```
  public abstract class BaseScoreRecord<T extends BaseScore> {
       public BaseScoreRecord(){
          init();
       }

       protected T[] mScoreHistory;
       protected int count=0;
       protected float finalScore;

       protected abstract void calcFinalScore();
       protected abstract void init();

       public float getFinalScore() {
           return mFinalScore;
       }

       public void addScoreRecord(T score){
           mScoreHistory[count] = score;
           count++;
       }
  }
  ```
- ...and `MyScoreRecord` which is a subclass of `BaseScoreRecord`

  ```
  public class MyScoreRecord extends BaseScoreRecord<LevelScore> {
       public MyScoreRecord(){
          init();
       }

       @Override
       protected void calcFinalScore(){
           //Does some stuff to calc final score from mScoreHistory
       }

       @Override
       protected void init(){
           mScoreHistory = new LevelScore[10];
           for (int i=0;i<mScoreHistory.length;i++){
               mScoreHistory[i] = new LevelScore();
           }
       };
  }
  ```

So, then I have `BaseGame` which has the following line:

```
protected BaseScoreRecord<? extends BaseScore> endGameRecord;
```

...and `MyGame` which is a subclass of `BaseGame`. `MyGame` includes the following methods:

```
@Override
protected void gameInit(){
    endGameRecord = new MyScoreRecord();  //endGameRecord initialised
}


protected void addLevelScore(LevelScore ls){
    mEndGameRecord.addScoreRecord(ls);
}
```

I get a compiler error on this last method:

```
The method addScoreRecord(capture#3-of ? extends BaseScore) 
in the type BaseScoreRecord <capture#3-of ? extends BaseScore>
is not applicable for the arguments (LevelScore)
```

...so I am evidentially doing something wrong regarding the generics, wildcards and the subclassing. If I lose the generics in `BaseGame` and `MyGame` it all seems to run without any nasty ClassCastException errors. Any pointers would be much appreciated. Maybe I have made things too complicated for myself?

Comment: What is `mEndGameRecord` in your `addLevelScore` method? and Where is your `EndGameScore` type?

Comment: @Rohit sorry. Well spotted. That is what it did say - I decided halfway through my post to change class names. Have edited post.

Answer (score 1):

You should declare that `MyScoreRecord` is actually a subclass of `BaseScoreRecord`, and parameterize it properly:

```
public class MyScoreRecord extends BaseScoreRecord<LevelScore>
```

If you are using Eclipse, for example, you will get warnings because the `@Override` annotations are not actually overriding anything. The above will also make the compiler enforce that `LevelScore` extends `BaseScore`.

Comment: Thanks! Ditto as above....and I checked through it too. Have edited post to reflect what I meant to put in and somehow omitted - my query still stands.

Comment: `mEndGameRecord` needs to be a `MyScoreRecord` for your statement to work.